# How to balance a redox equation in molecular form?

Tags: redox

I've spent a while trying to balance this equation in molecular form with no success.

$$\ce{Cu + HNO3 -> Cu(NO3)2 + 2NO + H2O}$$

I need to find the coefficient of HNO3, which is 8. However, this was my attempt:

$$\ce{Cu^0 + H + (NO3)- -> Cu^2 + 2(NO3)- + 2NO-2 + H2O }$$

$$\ce{Cu^0 -> Cu^2 + 2e- }$$
$$\ce{2x (NO3- + 2H^1 + e--> 2NO^0 + H2O)}$$

$$\ce{Cu^0 + 4H+ +2NO3- -> Cu^2+ + 4NO^0 + 2H2O + NO3^-}$$

Image of process: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrlST.jpg

NO3 is the spectator polyatomic ion I left out during my balancing. I have no idea whether I did it right and where to go from here. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the picture you attached you have successfully identified the species that gets oxidised
$$\ce{Cu -> Cu^2+ + 2e-}\tag1$$
and reduced, i.e. $\ce{NO3-}$. While balancing this reaction you have made a few mistakes. You cannot leave it out as a spectator ion, since some of it is involved in the reaction.
Consider the oxidation state in nitrate and nitrogen monoxide. How many electrons have to be transferred?

> three, nitrogen goes from $+5$ to $+2$ (you have only written one)

How many water molecules will be produced? How many protons are needed?

> Two water, four protons

Write down the full half reactions

> $$\ce{\overset{+5}{N}O3- + 4H+ + 3e- -> \overset{+2}{N}O + 2H2O}\tag2$$

Now you need to find the factors to multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$ with to balance out the electrons.

> $3\times(1)$ and $2\times(2)$

This results in the following equation

> $$\require{cancel}\ce{Cu + 2NO3- + 8H+ + \cancel{6e- } -> 3Cu^2+ + \cancel{6e- } + 2NO + 4H2O}$$

How many more nitrate ions do you need to charge balance the protons? What is the final balanced equation?

> Six more nitrate ions, giving a total of eight
>  $$\ce{Cu + 8HNO3 -> \underbrace{3Cu^2+ + 6NO3- }_{3Cu(NO3)2} + 2NO + 4H2O}$$

Comment: Thanks so much! I finally understood the mistakes I made and how to solve these problems.

Comment: I'd add that in the half-reactions the charge and the atoms have to balance. The utility is that you can use electrons  which really don't just float around in aqueous solution.